# Build android system from source

Tags: android, android-source

I've recently purchased Samsung Galaxy Android phone after using Openmoko phone for 2 years.

One of the reasons for choosing Android was is that it's open sourced.
I don't want to depend on phone maker to provide updates for my phone. I'd like to do it myself.
Right now I'm in research stage if it's worth the time or not. So here are the questions:

1. I found some tutorials for building ROM images from source. They tell that Android build script will ask for make of the phone before building kernel. Does it mean that all the phone specific stuff is handled by the script or I will have to do some voodoo before I can flash it onto my phone?
2. Drivers. How are they handled? Are they included in the source as binaries and added automatically (question 1) or will I have to dissect old firmware to get them and put in my build? I realize that would mean some problems with module/kernel versions compatibility.
3. Is there is something I'm not aware of that would prevent me from building my custom firmware or make it very time-consuming?

I'm not afraid of installing SDK's and toolchains, after all I'm an Openmoko owner.

Comment: I think this question would be fit better on superuser.com
Stackoverflow is for programming and developing questions in general. For hardware and software tweaking superuser would be the correct community. 

If I'm not the only one thinking that the question belongs on superuser the question will be auto migrated to superuser.com

Comment: Is it possible to use your own OS image on a consumer phone? I thought you needed one of Google's dev phones for that?

Comment: I was under the impression that only dev phones (including the nexus one) were able to handle custom images properly. With other phones it is possible to add custom roms, however you need to get the drivers (they are not open source generally, except most of the nexus one ones) and then add a load of tweaks to make it work well.

Comment: I was thinking about posting it on superuser but, after reading the FAQ:

and it's not about...
[...]
electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

Since my question is about cellphones I decided to post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's gonna be a *little* more complicated than that.

1. On any consumer Android phones I've seen, the user doesn't have root access to the OS.   So step one, would be finding an exploit to get root.
2. Even after you get root, all consumer Android phones "lock" the bootloader to prevent unauthorized OS images from being booted.
3. The Android OpenSource project only contains device drivers for a small number of phones (Google dev phones, possibly the Nexus One?).   For other phones, the drivers are proprietary binaries that the manufacturer loads on the phone.  They generally aren't available separately.

Even with all of those obstacles, some enterprising smart guys have managed to create custom "ROM's" that blend the OpenSource release with drivers ripped OEM install on the phone, etc.   CyanogenMod is one of the best known and is available for several different Android devices, but unfortunately the Samsung Galaxy does not currently appear to be one of the device supported by Cyanogen.

I found an old [link here](http://theunlockr.com/2010/04/05/how-to-load-a-custom-rom-on-the-samsung-galaxy/) to a guide to getting root on the Galaxy and loading a custom ROM on it, but unfortunately the ROM they link to doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore.  It might be worth doing some more exhaustive google searches to see if you can find anyone doing active development on the Galaxy.